# C++ Memory Allocation/Deallocation & FreeSpace Bug Error

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation

I am practicing memory allocation and disk management with C++. I just all of the work.. it just looks and seem's a little too easy. I am not sure if my pointer and my allocation and deallocations are correct. My Total FreeSpace looks like it will work, but it looks too basic. I just need someone's programming experience. When I try to run this code it gives me some kind of Error.

[Bug Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykcXp.jpg)

Please DO NOT ADD any new Global Variable.

```
const int MMSIZE = 60136;
  char MM[MMIZE];

 //** Initialize set up any data needed to manage the memory
void initializeMemory(void)
{
  //**increments through the POOL_SIZE
  for (int a = 0; a < MMSIZE; a++) {
      MM[a] = 'NULL';
  }
}

// return a pointer inside the memory
// If no chunk can accommodate aSize call onOutOfMemory()
void* allocate(int size)
{
  //******NOT SURE*******
  int *p = new int;
  *p = 5;

return ((void*) 0);
}

// Free up a chunk previously allocated 
void deallocate(void* mPointer)
{

//******NOT SURE*******
  int *p = new int;
  delete p;
  p = 0;
  p = new int(10);

}

//Scan the memory and return the total free space remaining
int remaining(void)
{
//******NOT SURE*******
  int free = 0;
  for (int a = 0; a < MMSIZE; a++)
  {
      if (MM[a] < MMSIZE)
      {
          free += a;
      }
  }

  int free2 = free - MMSIZE;
return free2;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this code does anything useful?

Comment: I don't think OP claims such -- it looks like OP is practicing and experimenting with memory allocation.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using, but it doesn't compile under g++.         `MM[a] = 'NULL';` is not valid.  Neither is `char MM[MMIZE];`.  Please post code that actually compiles.  You also have no `main()`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Studio, but you should be able to get it to tell you what line number your Access Violation Exception occurred.

Comment: Your `return ((void *)0);` in function `void* allocate(int size)` is screaming `Access Violation writing location 0x00000000`.

Comment: for NULL, you might #define NULL 0. You can then write MM[a] = NULL;  Or MM[a] = 0;   Also you could try searching for some similar, working open source code to see a working memory handling example.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks unfinished for even a sample but

```
 //** Initialize set up any data needed to manage the memory
void initializeMemory(void)
{
  //**increments through the POOL_SIZE
  for (int a = 0; a < MMSIZE; a++) {
      MM[a] = 'NULL';// <=== this should not even compile as the single quote should only take one character like '\x0' or 'N'
  }
}
```

should not even compile as the single quote should only take one character like '\x0' or 'N'
but post the complete module and i can help you more and maybe explain a few things.

Comment: Added in my main.cpp File

Comment: It's a multi-character literal, has type `int` and implementation-defined value. So this gives *multi-character character constant* and *implicit constant conversion overflow* warnings, but does compile.

Answer (score 0):

Without discussing other aspects of your code (such as memory leaking etc), the specific error you are getting most likely comes from `*int_pointer = 0xDEADBEEF;` line. `int_pointer` is equal to `0`, because `int_pointer = (long *)allocate(sizeof(long));` and your `void* allocate(int size)` with its `return ((void*) 0);` always returns `0`. So you are getting exactly that exception: attempting to write `0xDEADBEEF` at address `0x00000000`, which is a forbidden operation (there is some OS specific stuff at low addresses).